# Delete empty row created by subscription to service on ngOnInit()

Tags: typescript, service, angular7, ngoninit

I have a Material Data table, which the user can fill and empty by himself. The data, which gets into the table gets triggered by a service, which I initialized in the table component with `ngOnInit()`.

Code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._AS.transaction$.subscribe( transaction => {
        this.transaction = transaction;
        this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
        this.temp.push(this.transaction); // Stop this call on init somehow?
        this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
        this.ref.detectChanges();
        console.log(this.transaction);
      }
    );
  }
```

The problem is: There is always an empty row which gets pushed by the call `this.temp.push(this.transaction)`. Is there a way to stop this call for the first time or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used an alternative way:
After pushing the empty Transaction into the table I pop it afterwards, so that the table is empty again. Pushing data works now without problems.

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this._AS.transaction$.subscribe(transaction => {
          this.transaction = transaction;
          this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
          this.temp.push(this.transaction);
          this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
          this.ref.detectChanges();
        }
      );
      this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
      this.temp.pop();
      this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is it empty, because 'transaction' is?
So why don't you just use an if query?
Or you could declare a (bool) variable in your parent component and set it on true the first time you hit ngOnInit

```
constructor( public parentComponent: ParentComponent) {

}

ngOnInit() {
  if(parent.isInitialized) {
    this._AS.transaction$.subscribe( transaction => {
      this.transaction = transaction;
      this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();

      if(parent.isInitialized) {
        this.temp.push(this.transaction); // Stop this call on init somehow?
      } else {
        parent.isInitialized = true;
      }

      this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      console.log(this.transaction);
    } );
}
```

Comment: I just tried that. It didn't work. The empty row is gone and the bool is set to true. But if I want to add data to the table it doesn't display that data.

Comment: Oh okay, what if you do the if(parent.isInitialized in the subscribe closure? See edit